# Salesforce MVP nominations are open for 2020

Tags: discussion

The nomination period for the new class of Salesforce MVPs is now open.

- Submit nominations [here](https://nominations.salesforcemvps.com/s/)
- Find out about the program and criteria [here](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/mvp/)

We have a number of amazing MVPs contributing here at SFSE (complete list of MVPs is [here](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/mvp)), and some contributors who might make great additions to the program.

If you have someone to nominate or support for an existing MVP, now's the time to start writing!

**Correction**: all existing MVPs [have been renewed](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/nominate-a-salesforce-mvp-for-2021/) for the next class. Nominate those new folks!

Comment: We still cannot vote or nominate employees of Salesforce, am I right? Just thinking about you or Lukas Lunow etc.

Comment: Correct, Salesforce employees can't be MVPs.